# "Illegal Start of action" and "; expected" compiler errors

Tags: java

I'm getting 4 errors on one line of code

the line that reads "public action void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){" gets "Illegal start of action" twice and "; expected" twice.

I copied this code out of the Head First Java book, why the heck won't it compile?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui1 implements ActionListener{
    Jbutton button;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        SimpleGui1 gui = new SimpleGui1();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            button.setText("I've been clicked.");
        } //close actionPerformed
    } //close go()

}
```

Comment: in Java (as of 1.7) nested methods are invalid.

Comment: move actionPerfromed outside of go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a method inside another method. Move `actionPerformed` outside `go` block

```
 public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);


} //close go()



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            button.setText("I've been clicked.");
} //close actionPerformed
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys.  I get it now.  Why did my question get downvoted twice?  Did I do something wrong?